# How do i store a swf file name and location in mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, flash, dreamweaver, movie

Problem,
I cannot pre-view a flash movie in a php.page.
Question,
How, where, do i store a swf file name and location in mySQL database and then use this data to call it in the application?
Thanks for reading
Sabby77

Answer (score 0):

Problem, I cannot pre-view a flash movie in a php.page
- Why not? Can you give more details?

How, where, do i store a swf file name and location in mySQL database and then use this data to call it in the application?
- I can't answer "where" as this depends on your app structure , but you could save both the name & file location in your database. In your app, you can then get the values from the database & assign them to PHP variables.

If you're using SWFObject ,you could do something like this:

```
// $location = swf file location
// $name = swf file name
swfobject.embedSWF("(put your PHP tags here) echo $location./.$name; (put your PHP tags here)", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.115",    "expressInstall.swf");
```